# Facebook Open Graph - missed properties in debugger

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I have some problems with this website: http://www.southvillage.com/property/?mls=4439852 associated with Facebook Open Graph.

As you can see in the source there are all required meta tags added but when I test it using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.southvillage.com%2Fproperty%2F%3Fmls%3D4439852 it shows errors like: "The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.". Meanwhile as you can see everything is added there.

What can cause these problems? Is it associated with "id" in the link: ?mls=4439852 and Facebook cannot read it?

Website is done using WordPress.

Comment: It's because of this: `301 HTTP Redirect -> http://www.southvillage.com/property/` So you need to go find out why your site behaves different when the FB scraper request your original URL. (Wrongly configured plugins that try to detect requests by "bots" or stuff like that is often the culprit.)

Comment: I think it's the problem with the plugin I'm writting. This plugin should fetch data from XML and display it on a page, so I've created construction like this: https://gyazo.com/5cc825f987d27536ada1b4f354362e33 . It just works as my own function not associated with WordPress. Do you think I should do it in another way to avoid mentioned error with redirect? Does Facebook read GET in the url properly?

Comment: I don’t see what that is supposed to have to do with anything. Your og:url value is wrong, so you need to go find out where it comes from and fix it.

Comment: The reason of bad url was hosting provider. It displays properly url in the both places now. However it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `og:url`is `http://www.southvillage.com/property?mls=4439852`, but redirects to `http://www.southvillage.com/property/?mls=4439852` - notice the additional/missing (depending on how you look at it) slash after `property`. Fix it.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. Thank you!